# PDO update error nvalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of token

Tags: php, pdo

I'm writing a simple program but stuck on update query. Error show "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of token". Below is the code

```
class PDContr extends PDedit{

  private $userFirstName;
  private $userLastName;

  public function __construct($userFirstName, $userLastName){

    $this->userFirstName = $userFirstName;
    $this->userLastName = $userLastName;
  }

  public function pdedit(){
    if($this->emptyInput() == false){
      header("location: ../personaldetail.php?error=emptyinput");
      exit();
    }
    if($this->invaliduid() == false){
      header("location: ../personaldetail.php?error=userFirstname");
      exit();
    }
    $this->setUser($this->userFirstName, $this->userLastName);
  }
```

Below is the class extends to my database. Is it I didn't define the user_ID, so cannot execute the update query?

```
 class PDedit extends Dbh{
    
      protected function setUser($userFirstName, $userLastName){
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('UPDATE user SET user_FirstName = ?, user_LastName = ? WHERE user_ID = ?);');
    
        if(!$stmt->execute(array($userFirstName, $userLastName))){
            $stmt = null;
            header("location: ../personaldetail.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }
    
        $stmt = null;
    }
    
    }
```

Comment: Is the `user` a database? If not why extend the database class like this?

Comment: Yup. the user is the database.

Comment: Is the userID known when you try to call `setUser` method? How is the class invoked initially

Comment: I have another file to call out the setUser (userfirstname and userlistname), but didn't includes the userID. The question is I don't know where I can define the userID.

Comment: There is no context or clear indication how this works - *you* should know where/how to find the `user ID`. Is the user updating their own profile or are you (or an admin) updating the profile? Do you click on a hyperlink to begin the `edit` process or click a button... we do not know

Comment: Owner to update their own profile.  No hyperlink needed.  Just click on the button to update.

Comment: So the user has logged in and most likely a session has been set including their username & possibly other information? If that is so then assign the userID as a session variable and use that session variable when constructing / calling the `setUser($first,$last,$id)`

Comment: Are you meaning something like this?  $_SESSION["userID"] = $userID?

Comment: Basically yes. When the user logs in the password is verified and if all OK then you set the session variables. In the recordset that you return from the SQL query presumably you include this `userID` column? so retrieve that value and ANY/ALL other columns to be used as session variables and assign as such ( can be a single session variable using an array or object as value rather than lots of session variables if you like ) Then, whe your user wants to update his/her/its profile use that session variable in the parameter slots supplied to your `setUser( $first, $last, $userid )`

Answer (score 0):

You forget add `user_ID`:

```
protected function setUser($userFirstName, $userLastName, $userId = null){ // Add param here
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare('UPDATE user SET user_FirstName = ?, user_LastName = ? WHERE user_ID = ?);');
    
        if(!$stmt->execute(array($userFirstName, $userLastName, $userId))){
            $stmt = null;
            header("location: ../personaldetail.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }
    
        $stmt = null;
    }
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Unfortunately. it show the error message. Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')'